# How to perform an axios get request with route parameters in the URL?

Tags: redux, react-redux, axios

So, I have an action creator where I want to get data from my API endpoint.

The following works :

```
export function getData(){
    return function(dispatch){
        axios.get('/api/form/myuser/mytitle').then( (res) => {
            console.log(res.data);
            return dispatch(retrieve(res.data))
        })
        .catch( (err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
}
```

In my case, however, the API endpoint changes. 
I first do a server request to this URL : `/api/form/:userId/:title`
Then, what I actually want to do is the above action creator with an axios get request as follows on my client side :

```
axios.get('/api/form/:userId/:title')
```

A console log here obviously does not return the title String, it returns `:title`

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do ? If not, any suggestion how else ?

Comment: So you want the string to be formatted dynamically because the url will not be the same for every request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I found the answer to this :)

The solution lies in react-router. I was not familiar enough with react-router prior to this.

The trick is to define your params in your route path, wherever it is (your store, or the file where you define all your routes), as follows :

```
<Route path = "form/:userId/:formtitle" component = {Form} />
```

You can then access these params in your Form component via props like this :

```
this.props.params.userId 
this.props.params.formtitle
```

In order to have the above props available to your action creator, you can use them as parameters of the action creator you trigger in your component, as follows :

```
this.props.getData (this.props.params.userId, this.props.params.formtitle)
```

More details here : https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/08-index-routes

Comment: This is not an answer to the question you asked, which was "How to perform an axios get request with route parameters in the URL?"

Answer (score 3):

I think the template strings can be a comfortable solution for your problem. Please, don't hesitate to use Alt Gr + 7! :)

```
axios.get(`/api/form/${userId}/${title}`)
```

Be carefully with the undefined values.

https://developer.mozilla.org/hu/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals